# Is PHP buffer overflow possible?

Tags: php, buffer-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to conduct buffer overflow in PHP/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081281/how-to-conduct-buffer-overflow-in-php-python)

I was reading [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-lockdown/section6.html), when I came into this:

> A buffer overflow attack seeks to overflow the memory allocation buffer inside your PHP application or, more seriously, in Apache or the underlying operating system. Remember that you may be using a high-level language like PHP to code your Web applications, but at the end of the day, you're calling C (in the case of Apache) to do work. And C, like most low-level languages, has strict rules about allocation of memory..

What? I knew that PHP was well error-checked and so buffer overflow wasn't possible. Should I check user input length to avoid too big data flow?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is and in the [current change log](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) there has been 15 bug fixes related to it:

> - Fixed bug #61807 Buffer Overflow in apache_request_headers, CVE-2012-2329.
> - Fixed buffer overflow on overlog salt in crypt(). (Clément LECIGNE, Stas
> - Fixed bug #60965 (Buffer overflow on htmlspecialchars/entities with $double=false).
> - Fixed stack buffer overflow in socket_connect(). (CVE-2011-1938) Found by Mateusz Kocielski, Marek Kroemeke and Filip Palian. (Felipe)
> - Fixed possible buffer overflows in mysqlnd_list_fields, mysqlnd_change_user. (Andrey)
> - Fixed possible buffer overflows when handling error packets in mysqlnd. Reported by Stefan Esser. (Andrey)
> - Fixed a possible dechunking filter buffer overflow. Reported by Stefan Esser. (Pierre)
> - Fixed bug #42862 (IMAP toolkit crash: rfc822.c legacy routine buffer overflow). (Fixes CVE-2008-2829) (Dmitry)
> - Fixed possible stack buffer overflow in FastCGI SAPI. (Andrei Nigmatulin)
> - Fixed possible triggering of buffer overflows inside glibc implementations of the fnmatch(), setlocale() and glob() functions.
>     Reported by Laurent Gaffie.
> - Fixed bug #42222 (possible buffer overflow in php_openssl_make_REQ). (Pierre)
> - Fixed a remotely trigger-able buffer overflow inside make_http_soap_request(). (Ilia)
> - Fixed a buffer overflow inside user_filter_factory_create(). (Ilia)
> - Fixed a remotely trigger-able buffer overflow inside bundled libxmlrpc library. (Stas)

Comment: So, would you check every user input size to avoid buffer overflow?

Comment: @user1294101 No I wouldn't. If I knew about a buggy extension or code I would submit the bug report. You should check the size of user input as a normal validation.

Comment: Thanks, but then why not checking input size is unsafe? What can a too big input do?

Comment: @user1294101 I mean I check for input size as a normal validation routine, I.E. someone's bank account number is probably not megabytes long... Not because there might be a buffer overflow bug in `str_replace` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, same tutorial advises to use maxlength and php substr...  "The browser will keep users from entering a string that's too long for PHP or MySQL to handle safely (imagine if someone tried to type in a name with 1,000 characters),". Would it be a problem? I think it's wrong.

Comment: @Surferonthefall Don't rely on the browser to do anything for you, people can submit data to your server without using any browser. Client side is inherently untrustworthy.

Comment: how to check input size in php?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it can happen, when calling functions that are actually written using C/C++ (that'd be all core functions).

I believe those basic functions that PHP provides have been checked for errors like buffer overflow, but you cannot know for sure when using custom extensions though.

Comment: So, is checking every user input size a secure way?

Comment: No, I wouldn't do it. If the buffer overflow occurs, it is a PHP bug and should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, is data flood (let's pretend someone POSTs 50 mb of data) a problem?

Comment: Can be, however maximum post size can be controlled via config flag post_max_size (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Comment: currently I have memory_limit set to 54 mb, which affects post_max_size... Do you think is that a good limit? Thanks again

Comment: memory_limit is totally up to you and requirements of your application; you may need more memory if app is memory intensive, or face fatal errors when memory runs out. post_max_size is specifically there to distinguish between overall memory consumption and max post data size.

Answer (score 0):

Sure its 'possible.'  The question I would be more interested in is where do you think the attack vector is to do this (an upatched php bug, etc).  Also, i would think this is a much less likely target for exploit than other security issues.

Comment: I'd want to know if checking every user input size is a good idea.